# pkg_resources.VersionConflict when trying to use package

Tags: python, packaging

I have a [package I created](https://github.com/RuABraun/texterrors).

No matter if I install from source or from pypi when I try and use it I get an error:

```
  File "/home/seni/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 777, in resolve
    raise VersionConflict(dist, req).with_context(dependent_req)
pkg_resources.VersionConflict: (texterrors 0.0.4 (/home/seni/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages), Requirement.parse('texterrors==0.0.2'))
```

This happens even if I uninstall and make sure there are no related files remaining in site-packages. I've tried grepping for `requirements.txt` and cannot find any package that depends on this one.

I'm extremely confused.

Answer (score 0):

There was an old `.py` file from a previous version which did things differently in `~/.local/bin` which was getting picked up and contained the `texterrors==0.0.2` requirement.